# How can I use execl() function or other kinds of exec() functions to perform echo command?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have a question, I used the following program(fork() functions) to create a child process to overload another program using execl(). If I want to use echo command in the execl() functions or other kinds of exec() functions ,what should I do? I use following program, but it failed! the terminal gave me a warning:echo: cannot access hello world!: No such file or directory
this is parent!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>

   int main()
   {   pid_t childpid;
       childpid=fork();

       if(childpid==-1){
           perror("failed to fork");
           return 1;
           }
       if(childpid==0)
       {    
          execl("/bin/ls","echo","hello world!",NULL);
          perror("child failed to exec");
          return 1;
          }
       if(childpid!=wait(NULL)){
       perror("parent failed to wait due to signal or error");
       return 1;
       }
       sleep(5);
       printf("this is parent!\n");



       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Basically, I just want to use echo command in the exec() function, and use exec() to overload main function, but I am not sure how to use execl() function to perform echo command. I think maybe there is something wrong with the path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827939/handling-arguments-array-of-execvp,I think this also can help me solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

The command you are executing is:

```
/bin/ls "echo" "hello world!"
```

What you probably want to execute is (assuming you are using `bash`):

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo "hello world!"'
```

So use:

```
execl("/bin/bash","-c","echo \"hello world!\"",NULL);
```

And you probably want to check for errors before using `perror`.

---

Edit:

As per EOF's reccomendation you should probably use `system` call rather than `exec`. It handles creating the subprocess for you, and allows you to focus on the task at hand (namely invoking a shell command). The possible disadvantage is that it waits for the subprocess to die before continuing, but that's most likely not an issue (not in this case, anyway). It also ignores certain signals (`SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT`) which might not be desirable, depending on how you design your program.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me what does '-c' mean?

Comment: It basically specifies that what follows is a command, not a file name (for scripts, for example).

Comment: It's probably a better idea to use `system`, sure, but the author was asking for `exec`-related example. Should have probably included that in my answer.